# Angular stops working when injecting a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a resolve that I inject services and factories into. When I inject a factory I just made called ValidationMatrixFactory nothing works anymore. The homepage loads but links no longer resolve, basically clicking on anything has no effect. Angular does not throw any errors. Everything just stops working. I've tried multiple browsers, restarting IIS, all to no effect.

The console.log statement in the resolve is never hit. Here's the resolve:

```
        resolve: {
            eventData: ['$http', '$stateParams', 'ViewMatrixService', 'ValidationMatrixFactory', function ($http, $stateParams, ViewMatrixService, ValidationMatrixFactory) {
                console.log('EventId: ' + $stateParams.eventId);
                return $http.get('http://localhost:10569/api/eventView/' + $stateParams.eventId).then(function (response) {
                    ViewMatrixService.GenerateViewMatrix(response.data);
                    ValidationMatrixFactory.GenerateValidationMatrix(response.data);
                    return response.data;
                });
            }]
        }
```

Everything works if I take out the references to ValidationMatrixFactory. ValidationMatrixFactory is very similar to ViewMatrixService so I'm not sure why it's a problem now.

Here's ValidationMatrixFactory:

```
angular.module('myWebApp.services')
    .factory('ValidationMatrixFactory', function() {
        var ValidationMatrixFactory = {};

        ValidationMatrixFactory.GenerateValidationMatrix = function (eventData) {
            var currentStage = eventData.CoreEvent.Stage;
            initializeValidationMatrix();
            determineRequiredFields(currentStage);
        }

        function initializeValidationMatrix() {
            ValidationMatrixFactory.EventTitleRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.EventSummaryRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.DesiredPublicationDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.DesiredEffectiveDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.ReasonForDesiredEffectiveDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.AssessmentTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.FRSOTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.BLRTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.SSOTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.BLSOTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.FSOTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.PublicationTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.EffectiveTargetDateRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.RMRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.PublisherRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.MoPRequired = false;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.PriorityRequired = false;
        }

        function determineRequiredFields(currentStage) {
            ValidationMatrixFactory.EventTitleRequired = true;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.EventSummaryRequired = true;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.ReasonForDesiredEffectiveDateRequired = true;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.DesiredPublicationDateRequired = true;
            ValidationMatrixFactory.DesiredEffectiveDateRequired = true;

            if (currentStage.StageNumber > 1) {
                ValidationMatrixFactory.AssessmentTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.FRSOTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.BLRTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.SSOTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.BLSOTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.FSOTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.PublicationTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.EffectiveTargetDateRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.RMRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.PublisherRequired = true;
                ValidationMatrixFactory.MoPRequired = true;
            }

            if (currentStage.StageNumber > 2) {
                ValidationMatrixFactory.PriorityRequired = true;
            }
        }

        ValidationMatrixFactory.ValidateFields = function (saveType) {

        }
    });
```

I have a reference to the script in index.html.

```
    <script src="libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/angular/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/uiboostrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/dirPagination/dirPagination.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/angular-loading-bar/loading-bar.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view.matrix.service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validation.matrix.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="js/utility.service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="partials/events/EventCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="partials/events/EventHeaderCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="partials/events/EventOverviewTabCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="partials/events/EventAdditionalInformationTabCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="partials/events/EventDSOTabCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="partials/events/EventFooterCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nonAngular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show the console output?  Generally it includes a link to angularjs.org docs with useful links.

Comment: @robrich That's the problem. No error is raised. It fails silently.

Comment: Did you include a dependency in 'myWebApp.services' module?

Comment: @YanivEfraim Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean. `myWebApp.services` is referenced at the beginning of `ValidationMatrixFactory`.

Comment: return `ValidationMatrixFactory` object from the factory.

Comment: @Saad Thank you! That was it! If you turn you comment into an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return `ValidationMatrixFactory`object from factory.

`.factory` is a method which we generally call with a name and a function as parameters. This function is just a function which must return an object. If you don't return anything, angular will get stuck in infinite digest.

If you used `.service`, it was fine to not return anything. That's because a service is a constructor function. You can have `this` in the service function and add property to `this`.

**Update**

It looks like before angularjs version 1.3.4, no error was thrown. From 1.3.4, error is thrown for infinite digest.

Comment: @Legion: By the way, which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Angular Version 1.4.8